# What concise function $f$ satisfies $\prod_{i=1}^n \prod_{j=1}^n a_{i,j} = f \left( \det(\mathbf{A}) \operatorname{Adj}(\mathbf{A})^{-1} \right)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, products

Let $\mathbf{A} = [a_{i,j}]$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with determinant $\det (\mathbf{A})$. Consider the equality

$$\prod_{i=1}^n \prod_{j=1}^n a_{i,j} = f \left(\det(\mathbf{A}) \operatorname{Adj}(\mathbf{A})^{-1} \right)$$

where $f$ computes the product of the elements $\det(\mathbf{A}) \operatorname{Adj}(\mathbf{A})^{-1}$.

Since $\mathbf{A} = \det(\mathbf{A}) \operatorname{Adj}(\mathbf{A})^{-1}$, I tried to expand this expression. The product of the entries on the right would equal the product of the entries on the left... But I drowned in a huge puddle of series and products. I (unwisely) tried to use the Laplace expansion theorem.

Is there a concise expansion formula to express $f$?

Comment: There cannot be any such function. Applying the formula for $diag [a,1,1...,1]$ we see that $f(a)=0$ for all $a$. Did I mis-understand the question?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Wouldn't $f(a) = 0\ \forall a \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbf{A} = \operatorname{Diag}[a, 1, ..., 1]$ imply that $f$ is not surjective rather than non-existent?

Comment: LHS is not a function of $\det (A)$ alone. As far as I can see your question does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Assume there is such a function $f$ and let
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
~~~~~~~~~~~~
B = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

then we have $\det A = \det B = 1$ and the product of the entries is $0$ for $A$ and $2$ for $B$. We therefore get
$$
 0 = f(\det A) = f(1) = f(\det B) = 2
$$
which is cotradictory.

---

**Comment:** This was an answer to the first version of the question, which was whether there is a function which satisfies $\Pi_{i,j} a_{i,j} = f (\det A)$.

Comment: Okay, I see the problem with my original question. I have edited.